Help with understanding Isometric deformation of helicoid to catenoid
It can be shown that a coordinate transformation exemplifies the flexibility of a helicoid and catenoid and thus they're isometric via:
\begin{equation}
x(u,v) = \cos \alpha \sinh v \sin u + \sin \alpha \cosh v \cos u
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
y(u,v) = -\cos \alpha \sinh v \cos u + \sin \alpha \cosh v \sin u
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
z(u,v) = u \cos \alpha + v \sin \alpha
\end{equation}
for $v$ the vertical coordinate and $u$ the polar angle. Here, alpha is a parameter that when varied from $0$ to $\pi / 2$ makes the equations isometrically deform a helicoid to a catenoid. I believe if you keep going you get a helicoid again but it's chirality swaps.
I want to understand the characteristic equation that describes the surface, something of the form $F(x,y,z) = 0$. If we swap $ \ \cos \alpha \ $ with $ \ \sin \alpha \ $, the deformation is reversed; that is, the surface begins as a helicoid and turns into a catenoid.
I'm probably not seeing something obvious about the coordinate transformation, but for the case where we swap $ \cos \alpha $ with $ \sin \alpha $, setting $\alpha = 0$ gives:
\begin{equation}
x(u,v) = \cosh v \cos u, \ \ y(u,v) = \cosh v \sin u, \ \ z(u,v) = v
\end{equation}
Note that I'm keeping the negative sign with the cosine in the equation for $y$ with it, so when I swap the sine and cosine in y, the cosine and negative stay together. This is clearly a generic catenoid where the radius at $v = 0$ is $1$. The characeristic equation would be $x^2 + y^2 = z^2 \ \text{for} \ z = \cosh^2 v$.
When we go to $\alpha = \pi / 2$, (still in the case where we've swapped the $\sin \alpha \ \text{and} \cos \alpha$ ), we get:
\begin{equation}
x(u,v) = \sinh v \sin u, \ y(u,v) = -\sinh v \cos u, \ z(u,v) = u
\end{equation}
Compared to a regular helicoid of radius 1: $x = z \cos u = u \cos u, \ y = z \sin u = u \sin u, \ z = u$, $x$ and $y$ have been "swapped", which doesn't quite affect anything except changing how the helicoid begins plotting if one varied $u$ increasingly from 0. The metric is the same. But now, we still get a "catenoidal" characteristic equation: $x^2 + y^2 = \sinh^2 v$. Doesn't this also describe a catenoid? I know that's a bit of a silly question because the transformation shows that a catenoid and helicoid are isometric to each other, but isn't the uniqueness of a helicoid due to the fact that $z$ is equal to the polar angle? Since $z$ doesn't have any $v$ dependence, what would the equation $F(x,y,z) = 0$ look like? I guess I can't see how exactly we get helicoidal features for the surface instead of catenoidal

This is very confusing. Why do we need to switch $\cos\alpha$ and $\sin\alpha$ to talk about comparing particular values of $\alpha$?

@TedShifrin We don't. I chose to so that for $\alpha = 0$, the surface begins as a catenoid and the equations appear as such in an obvious way to me.
